# Amstock Chart Mouse Wheel Scroll does not work perfectly

Tags: amcharts

### Is it a bug in amstock chart?

Mouse Scrolling is working fine for big period but does not work with small periods.

Amstock Chart Multiple axis example: [`http://www.amcharts.com/tips/multiple-value-axes-stock-chart/`](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/multiple-value-axes-stock-chart/)

Here is jsfiddle for above example: http://jsfiddle.net/qmbjyxsr/

My program on which i am working: http://jsfiddle.net/8tLtdx8g/

Mouse Scroll Works for big periods:

[image: Mouse Scroll Works for big periods]

Mouse Scrolling does not work for small period:
[image: Mouse Scrolling does not work for small period:]

Comment: The mouse wheel scrolling works for me on both of the fiddles that you linked to. Maybe you can explain what exactly does not work? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it works for me but only for bigger period(above image1) not for small period(above image2). Does it works same for you for both above periods?

Comment: Yup. Works OK with any period, including very small. Which browser are you using BTW?

Comment: Strange.!! I use Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116, and it is not working here. Same problem with firefox 37.0.2. And these both browsers are updated to there latest versions. What can be the problem then?

Comment: Not sure, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Which browser are you using?